# How to run a pytest-bdd test?

Tags: pytest, python-behave

I am not understanding how to properly run a simple test(feature file and python file)
with the library `pytest-bdd`.

From the official [documentation](https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#), I can't understand what command to issue to run a test.

I tried using `pytest` command, but I saw the NO test ran.
Do I need to use another library `behave` to run a feature file?

Answer (score 10):

I figured out trying for 2 days,that ,

for running a `pytest-bdd` test, there are certain requirements, at least in my view.

1. put both the `feature file` and `python file` in the same directory (maybe this can be changed with configuration files)
2. the `python file` name needs to **start** with `test_`
3. the `python file` needs to contain **a method** of which name will **start** with `test_`
4. the method starting with `test_` , need to be assigned to the `@scenario` sentence
5. to **run** the test, issue `pytest` command in the same directory(maybe it is also configurable)
6. After issuing you will **only** see the **method** with the name starting with `test_` has passed, but all the tests **actually ran**. To test, you can `assert False` in any `@when` or `@then` annotated method, it will throw errors.

The system contained : `pytest-bdd==3.0.2` (copied from `pip freeze` output)

Comment: This could stand to be cleared up in the actual documentation for `pytest-bdd`. I thought I had followed their setup and ran pytest to no avail. This worked.

Comment: Instead of requirements 3 & 4 - you can tell pytest-bdd about the feature file with ´scenarios('./my_test.feature')´ at the start of your python file. Then, all defined Scenarios from the feature file will be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Features files and python files can be placed in different folders using the *bdd_features_base_dir* hook provided by *pytest-bdd*; I think it is better having features files in different folders too.

Here you can see a working example (a simple hello world BDD test):

- https://github.com/davidemoro/pytest-play-docker/tree/master/tests
- https://github.com/davidemoro/pytest-play-docker/blob/master/tests/pytest.ini (see *bdd_features_base_dir* in *[pytest]* section)
- https://github.com/davidemoro/pytest-play-docker/tree/master/tests/bdd

If you want to try out pytest-bdd without installation you can use Docker. Create a folder with inside your pytest BDD files and if you want a separate *features* folder targeted in *bdd_features_base_dir* and run:

> docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/src davidemoro/pytest-play:latest

Answer (score 1):

I've found out, that in the python file you don't have to put:

> the method starting with test_ , need to be assigned to the @scenario sentence

You can just add: scenarios("") - to allow the tests to be started, which are using steps defined in this specific python file.

Remember to import scenarios!: from pytest_bdd import scenarios

Example:
[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs6JH.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Command..**

```
 pytest -v path_to_test_file.py
```

**Things to note here..**

1. Check format of feature file as filename.feature
2. Always `__init__` modules, otherwise test-runner will not find test files
3. Glue right step definitions to test function
4. Add feature in features module
5. If you are using python3 execute test with python3

**So,**

```
python3 -m pytest -v path_to_test_file.py
```

**Documentation**

https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#